# Preventing overlapping layout animations on a ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview

I have a `listView` that has a layout animation that fades in each item one at a time.

```
  lac = new LayoutAnimationController(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.listview_2), 0.25f);
    listOptions.setLayoutAnimation(lac);
    listOptions.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
```

When the user selects an item, the `listView` displays a new set of items - each fading in one at a time. However, if the fade in animation of the items has not completed when the user selects an item and causes a new set to fade in, then these animations overlap causing and the previous items can be seen while the new ones are fading in. It looks like a blinking glitch on the `ListView`.

`onItemClick()`, even if I call `listView.getLayoutAnimation.getAnimation().cancel();` I still get the same blinking problem.
I have also tried `listView.clearAnimation();`, still didn't work.
I have also tried: `listView.setLayoutAnimation(null);` and resetting. Still didn't work.

It appears I am unable to stop or cancel the animation!
All I want to do is, `onItemclick()` in my `listView`, to stop the animation or empty / clear the `listView` then reload the new items into the listView and fade them in using the animation, with no overlap - and therefore - no blinking glitch.

I do not want to disable the `listView` until the animation completes, then re-enable, because it can create awkwardly long wait times.

Answer (score 0):

Animation in ListViews are challenging which is one of the reasons Google released RecyclerView. However, this video may have some clues for how to make this work for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs

Comment: This is a helpful video, but not necessarily for my problem. Thanks for the share tho